# How to pass a SystemVerilog struct containing a dynamic array via DPI-C?

Tags: struct, verilog, dynamic-arrays

Here is a minimal working example of the problem:

Below example compiles fine (using Cadence Incisive/Xcelium) **if I comment out** the `import "DPI-C"` statement and the call to `print_object(s);`.

So that proves that the struct with dynamic array is a legal SystemVerilog syntax.

But if I try to pass the same struct via DPI-C, I get the error:

> xmvlog: *E,UNUSAG (tb.sv,10|62): unsupported element in unpacked struct datatype in formal argument.

```systemverilog
program top;

  typedef struct {
    int scalar_int;
    int dyn_arr_int[];
  } my_struct_s;

  import "DPI-C" function void print_object(input my_struct_s s);
  // Cannot pass a dynamic-array containing struct via DPI-C.

  //   import "DPI-C" function void print_object(input my_struct_s s);
  //                                                               |
  // xmvlog: *E,UNUSAG (tb.sv,10|62): unsupported element in unpacked struct datatype in formal argument.

  initial begin
    my_struct_s s;

    s.scalar_int = 100;
    s.dyn_arr_int = '{25, 35, 45};

    $display("Value of the struct printed from SV: %p", s);
    print_object(s);

    $finish;
  end

endprogram : top
```

---

So the question is:

Is there a workaround to pass structs with dynamic arrays to the C side? Is there a way to pass structs with "pointers" to those dynamic arrays? Or any other way?

*One workaround is to pass a struct with a static array of some "max" size and also pass a scalar integer storing the length of actual data that's a subset of that static array. But that's a very ugly workaround, requires overhead in SystemVerilog to calculate the lengths and to populate that static array, and is also probably inefficient compared to passing just the dynamic array.*

Comment: it is unclear if a struct with dynamic array can be passed to an import function. However, the dynamic arrays themselves can be passed to the import (but not to the export) function as arguments. So, try to pass it as a separate argument instead.

Comment: @Serge Thanks. I am familiar with passing dynamic arrays separately. I have a case where I have a struct with a huge assortment of values; some being scalar ints and reals and some being dynamic arrays of ints. And to be preferable to have all those related values be in a single struct. Having all those parameters separate will result in an unwieldy signature with dozens of arguments. So I'm looking a struct based value passing if possible. If dynamic arrays in structs are not possible, then I am hoping to learn about some creative way to get around that limitation if someone has one :).